# Xamarin Faster then listview

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

Im buildining a novel-manga app.

When i came to novels there was about 2000 chapthers and i need to render them all at once.

Im using a listview to render them but its to damnt slow.

I was wondering if there is a faster solution like a renderer or somthing i could build that will work faster.

Here is my current XAML

```html
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters}"
                      x:Name="grdChapters"
                      ItemSelected="GrdChapters_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="5" HeightRequest="30">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource header}" FontAttributes="None" />
                                    <Image Source="right.png" HorizontalOptions="End" IsVisible="{Binding Completed}" WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16" Aspect="AspectFit" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <BoxView  Style="{StaticResource lightLine}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: look at the new CollectionView

Comment: Is it faster? will test it right now thx

Comment: Belive it or not its slower:)

Comment: have you looked at using FFImageLoading for the images?  I imagine that's your real bottleneck

Comment: Im not using dynamic imgae its only a resource icon. so no caching is needed. the problem here is the total rows

Comment: Have you looked at the caching settings for ListView?  I'd also consider loading on demand rather than loading all 2000 at once.

Comment: yes not helping, im looking now at recylerview. will see how if it work better

Comment: Is recylerview faster？ I also recommend you to load more as you scroll or you can load 500 every time.

Comment: recylerview was faster, it was like dynamicly buildning the data by adding label. but it limited me to much. there was no support for click event and Binding

Comment: Ok,thanks for your information, I would do a test later.

Answer (score 0):

The [RecycleElementAndDataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#recycleelementanddatatemplate) should improve your performance, because even though you're not using any dynamic images, the datatamplate is the same for all of the items in the list and it'll get optimized.

If that doesn't help, I'd recommend using the [glidex](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/glidex) library for Xamarin.Android, it makes scrolling a lot smoother.

Comment: RecycleElementAndDataTemplate freeze my listview. cant event click on the items :)

Comment: Weird, perhaps try using the  CollectionView instead? I'm starting to get out of options haha

Comment: Th only solution i got, is to load more as i scroll, so i build my own listview. but i want to render them all if possiable. on java is very fast but not xamarin